# Create a view with a cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql

I try to create a view with the resultset of a cursor returned by a function.

I create the function return cursor `SELECT custom_util.Error_Ex_Dep from dual`

And when I try to create the view with :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW CUSTOM_V_ERREUR_E_D AS
   SELECT custom_util.Error_Ex_Dep 
     from dual
```

I get `ORA-02345`.

Comment: Use a pipelined function, return a nested table of record type and select from that function table.

Comment: So i need to create a new type in the schema, and and return this type ?

Comment: Yup. Create a record type. Create a nested table type of this record type. Then create a pipelined function that returns data of this nested table type.

Comment: Hello, after create the new record and create a function return this record. I call the new function from a view and i get the ORA-06575.

Comment: I enclose the ticket.